# Ruby - UDP - How to spoof IP and Port Number

Tags: ruby, udp, spoofing

I've been messing about with some sample client and server code for sending and receiving UDP packets, here's what I'm doing for the send

```
require 'socket'
s = UDPSocket.new
s.send("hello", 0, 'localhost', 1234)
```

Is it possible to somehow use a fake IP address and port number when sending? haven't come across anything online with any examples of how to do so.

Comment: It depends on your local binding for that socket.

Comment: Can you possibly elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

You need to [`bind`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.0/libdoc/socket/rdoc/UDPSocket.html) the socket before calling `send`:

```
require 'socket'

s = UDPSocket.new
s.bind('128.100.8.6', 1253)

s.send(...)
```

Keep in mind that your upstream is in no way responsible for delivering "spoofed" packets and that many providers will dump these if they're not originating in their network.

Comment: Thanks. This allows me to specify the port number, but if I want to use a fake IP address, then I get - Can't assign requested address - bind(2) for "'128.100.8.6'" port 1253 (Errno::EADDRNOTAVAIL). Is there any way around this?

Comment: What I'm actually trying to achieve here is: the client sends a packet to the server, the server then takes the port number and ip address of the sender and forwards it on to another server, so it looks like the original request came from the client.

Comment: That style of firewall popping depends on your provider *not* doing source filtering, something many have to do now to prevent UDP-based DDOS attacks. Assuming they allow it, you may need to use raw sockets to spoof everything, and that's a lot more work.